# Нельзя ссылаться на конструктор копирования

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class& operator=(const Class&&)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Class c1;
    Class c3(c1);

    return 0;
}
```

Почему при добавлении в класс

```
Class& operator=(const Class&&)
```

visual-studio-2017 пишет:

> E1776 на функцию "Class::Class(const Class &)" (объявлено неявно)
>   нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена

Должен же быть стандартный конструктор копирования.

Comment: [rule of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), [правило трех/пяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно современному видению этого вопроса, если пользователь явно предоставляет *любую* функцию из Правила Пяти (конструктор копирования, конструктор перемещения, копирующий оператор присваивания, перемещающий оператор присваивания, деструктор), это в идеале *должно* приводить к автоматическому подавлению неявной генерации всех остальных функций Правила Пяти.

Однако, для совместимости с существующим кодом, т.е. с "классическим" С++98 поведением, на текущий момент (в стандарте С++17) это правило реализуется лишь частично, следующим "компромиссным" образом:

1. Явно предоставленные пользователем функции из "классического" Правила Трех (конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания, деструктор) *не* подавляют неявную генерацию друг друга, но подавляют генерацию конструктора перемещения и перемещающего оператора присваивания.
2. Явно предоставленная пользователем "новая" функция из Правила Пяти (конструктор перемещения, перемещающий оператор присваивания) подавляет неявную генерацию всех остальных функций из Правила Пяти.

Вы в своем коде явно предоставили перемещающий оператор присваивания. Это заставило сработать пункт 2 и все остальные функции Правила Пяти были удалены. Если бы вы объявили оператор присваивания с параметром типа `const Class &`, то конструктор копирования никуда бы не пропал (согласно пункту 1). Но как только в вашем коде появляется `&&`, о совместимости с C++98 можно уже не беспокоиться. (Отдельный вопрос - зачем вам понадобился такой странный тип параметра `const Class &&`? Чего вы пытались достичь?)

Поведение, описанное пунктом 1, является устаревшим и в будущем будет упразднено. То есть любая явно предоставленная функция Правила Пяти будет подавлять генерацию всех остальных. Однако как скоро это произойдет - можно только гадать.

Comment: [Поведение, описанное пунктом 1, является устаревшим и в будущем будет упразднено.] Это катастрофическим образом скажется на обратной совместимости миллиардов строк кода. Поэтому вряд-ли это будет упразднено.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Возможно, вы правы. K&R объявления функций являются obsolescent с 89 года, но никто не осмеливается их убрать из С. С другой стороны narrowing conversions в `{}` в С++ смело запретили... Преобразование строкового литерала к неконстантному указателю - тоже. Поживем - увидим.

Comment: [K&R объявления функций являются obsolescent с 89 года] По моим понятиям некоторые сейчас работающие версии ядер Линукса-Юникса до сих пор содержат код, написанный задолго до 89 года. Как-то я заглянул в хедер Линукса, а там переменные до первой скобки {. Потому и не убирают. Кстати, можно написать инструмент-анализатор кода, который покажет какой процент устарелых конструкций используется в коде. Обработать этим инструментом какой-нибудь большой репозиторий кода вроде sourceforge. Если конструкция используется меньше чем 1%, то удалять из стандарта. Если больше, то оставлять. Научный подход.

Answer (score 3):

При наличии в классе хотя бы одного явного конструктора копирования / перемещения или соответствующего оператора присваивания другие не генерируются компилятором.

Comment: Странно, раньше генерировались. :-(